# Flip Text Without CSS Transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clock where each hands are words (e.g: **< p >WORD< /p >**) but as they pass 180deg they ofc turn upside down.
Normally flipping it using transform (like rotate) would be no biggie but as transform is the only thing setting the hands at the correct time I can't use any transform css that would interfere

is there *any other* way of flipping the text as soon as it passes 180deg?

CSS example:

```
#shortHand{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 70%;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%; }
```

Javascript example setting time:

```
shortHand.style.transform = `rotate(${currH}deg)`;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your example ? some more code to replicate the actual state ?

Comment: Use one element for pre-180 degrees, another for past-180 degrees, show only one at the time

Comment: @DaniP Miguel had a good answer below using scale instead of rotate, I had seen this while googling but it wouldn't work because I forgot to reverse the scale from 1 -> -1 and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

This will flip the text every time it hits 180 degrees:

HTML

```
 <div id="shortHand">
  <span>word</span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#shortHand {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#shortHand span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
var shortHand = document.querySelector('#shortHand');
var shortHandWord = document.querySelector('#shortHand span');

var deg = 270;
var i = -1;

setInterval(function() {
  shortHand.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;

  if (deg % 180 === 90) {
    i *= -1;
    shortHandWord.style.transform = `scale(${i})`;
  }

  deg++;
}, 10);
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8nr98381/6/**

Comment: I tried span and scale earlier but forgot to reverse "i" and gave up too soon. With some modifications this worked as intended, Cheers!

Comment: As per https://jsfiddle.net/8nr98381/8/ this will continue to ascend indefinitely. Is this a problem in practice?

Comment: I know that - it was more of an idle curiosity as to whether that code would eventually explode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try vertical text with CSS3 `writing-mode` property, here is a well written article about `writing-mode` with CSS3:

[generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes](http://generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes)

You can also refer about browser support for `writing-mode` property at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode)

Hope this will work!